# WebSockets on CentOS 7 after closing console

Tags: php, apache, websocket

When I open console and write `php server.php` websockets work well. But when I close the session, websockets stop working. How can I make it to work all the time? This is my `server.php` file - nothing complicated:

```
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new WebSocket() // <-- My class, ignore it
        )
    ),
    SERVER_PORT,
    SERVER_HOST
);

$server->run();
```

Running apache 2.4.6 with PHP 5.6 on CentOS 7.

Comment: When you close console you also close your app. Use screens Out of screen use : ctrl+A  AND ctrl + D .

Comment: https://uisapp2.iu.edu/confluence-prd/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=115540034

Comment: How can this helps me? I don't need `Out of screen` but websockets to work until I stop it somehow (like service), it needs to run everytime.

Comment: Anyway: `-bash: screen: command not found`.

Comment: Create screen intro that screen run your socket , then you can leave screen also close session (close console terminal) and your webSocket will work night and day !

Comment: I see now, seems working, thanks.

Comment: Today I came to check the status and WebSockets were down. There was no reboot, because `screen -list` had same list as yesterday, but it was just clear black (also no cursor to type) and I had to start WS manually again. So screens are not good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way - create own service to run websockets in the background. For me it is easier to maintain. Here are my steps (EPEL required):

```
$ yum install iperf3
$ adduser wsworker -s /sbin/nologin
$ vi /etc/systemd/system/websockets.service
```

Then insert the content (change the ExecStart to your own):

```
[Unit]
Description=WebSockets Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=wsworker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/php /var/www/public/server.php
Restart=on-abort


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Reload systemd and start new service:

```
$ systemctl daemon-reload
$ systemctl start websockets
```

Start service at the boot:

```
$ systemctl enable websockets
```

Stop server:

```
$ systemctl stop websockets
```

[Original article](https://scottlinux.com/2014/12/08/how-to-create-a-systemd-service-in-linux-centos-7/)

Answer (score 0):

Install screen tool for linux :

> yum -y install screen

Create new screen :

```
screen -S SESSIONNAME
```

Return to screen :

```
screen -r SESSIONNAME
```

Exit from screen :

```
 ctrl + a + d
```

When you open screen : navigate to the path of your app and start it .
When you wanna go out use ctrl + a + d . When you want to go back use : screen -r SESSIONNAME .

Screen is not reason for your problems 100% . If your application go down for one day you must check for ***memory leaks*** or some other bug in app.

At the moment go to screen -r SESSIONNAME to see what is happen intro your screen .

Comment: I get it, but I found a better way (for me) with custom service, which I can enable to run at the reboot and is more handy than screens.